# Generating random graph in r

Tags: r, graph

I would like to generate a grandom graph in R using any of the packages.

The desired output would be a two column matrix with the first column listing agents and the second column their connections of the following form:

```
1 3
1 4
1 6
1 7
2 2
2 5
3 9
3 11
3 32
3 43
3 2
4 5
```

I would like to be able to specify the average degree and minimum and maximum number of contacts.

What is the easiest way of doing this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since you don't specify the need for anything other than just a graph we ca do this very simply:

```
actor     <- sample(1:4, 10, replace=TRUE)
receiver  <- sample(3:43, 10, replace=TRUE)
graph     <- cbind(actor,receiver)
```

if you want something more specific have a look at `igraph` for instance

```
library(igraph)
graph <- erdos.renyi.game(21, 0.3, type=c("gnp", "gnm"),
              directed = FALSE, loops = FALSE)

# here the 0.3 is the probability of ties and 21 is the number of nodes
# this is a one mode network
```

or using package `bipartite` which focuses specifically on two mode networks:

```
library(bipartite)
web <- genweb(N1 = 5, N2 = 10, dens = 2)
web2edges(web,return=TRUE)

# here N1 is the number of nodes in set 1 and N2 the number of nodes in set 2
# and dens the average number of ties per node
```

There are many things to take into account, for instance if you want to constrain the degree distribution, probablity of ties between agents etc.

Comment: yes, tis is pretty much what I would like to have. This would be essentially identical to a random graph as in a social network right? ps. just to gain extra insight: what sort of things are you referring to by: "the need for anything other than just a graph" ?

Comment: I'm sorry I just realized that my question is missing the essential part. I have edited it. Sorry

Comment: why do you include both ER forms in your `type` argument? I'm trying to understand how this impacts the object `graph` vs just using one or the other